# Связать контакт со сделкой amoCrm

Tags: php, api

Не могу решить задачу, описанную в заголовке.
Пробовал как только можно: создать сначала контакт, добавить полученный в ответе объект контакта к сделке, пробовал сразу к сделке прикрепить новый контакт в виде ассоциативного массива. Как я понимаю, API у них часто обновляется. Подскажите, какой сейчас будет правильный способ это сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте контакт, получаете id, привязываете к сделке (лиду). Всё просто, API не меняется часто – просто надо внимательнее читать.

В `api/v4/leads` [POST] передаёте в payload для создания лида следующее, чтобы привязать контакт:

```
'_embedded' => [
    'contacts' => [
        [
            'id' => $contact['_embedded']['contacts'][0]['id']
        ]
    ]
],
```

Это всё в документации и описано: https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/crm_platform/leads-api#leads-add

Comment: Попробовал. Ошибок нет, но контакт к сделке не прикрепляется.

Comment: Ну должно работать. Токен не просрочен?

Comment: Извиняюсь, всё нормально. Мои глупые ошибки по невнимательности. Большое спасибо за помощь.